# Convert a for loop to a Multi-threaded chunk

Tags: java, multithreading, for-loop, executorservice

I have a following piece for loop in a function which I intended to parallelize but not sure if the load of multiple threads will overweight the benefit of concurrency.

All I need is to send different log files to corresponding receivers. For the timebeing lets say number of receivers wont more than 10. Instead of sending log files back to back, is it more efficient if I send them all parallel?

```
for(int i=0; i < receiversList.size(); i++)
        {
            String receiverURL = serverURL + receiversList.get(i);
            HttpPost method = new HttpPost(receiverURL);

            String logPath = logFilesPath + logFilesList.get(i);
            messagesList = readMsg(logPath);

            for (String message : messagesList) {
                StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(message);
                log.info("Sending message:");
                log.info(message + "\n");
                method.setEntity(entity);
                if (receiverURL.startsWith("https")) {
                    processAuthentication(method, username, password);
                }
                httpClient.execute(method).getEntity().getContent().close();
            }
            Thread.sleep(500); // Waiting time for the message to be sent
        }
```

Also please tell me how can I make it parallel if it is gonna work? Should I do it manual or use ExecutorService?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All I need is to send different log files to corresponding receivers. For the time being lets say number of receivers won't be more than 10. Instead of sending log files back to back, is it more efficient if I send them all parallel?

There are a lot of questions to be asked before we can determine if doing this in parallel will buy you anything.  You mentioned "receivers" but are you really talking about different receiving servers on different web addresses or are all threads sending their log files to the same server?  If it is the latter then chances are you will get very little improvement in speed with concurrency.  A single thread should be able to fill the network pipeline just fine.

Also, you probably would get no speed up if the messages are small.  Only large messages would take any time and give you any true savings if they were sent in parallel.

I'm most familiar with the `ExecutorService` classes.  You could do something like:

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
...
threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
    // you could create your own Runnable class if each one needs its own httpClient
    public void run() {
          StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(message);
          ...
          // we assume that the client is some sort of pooling client
          httpClient.execute(method).getEntity().getContent().close();
      }
    }
});
```

What *will* be good is if you want to queue up these messages and send them in a background thread to not slow down your program.  Then you could submit the messages to the `threadPool` and keep on moving.  Or you could put them in `BlockingQueue<String>` and have a thread taking from the `BlockingQueue` and calling the `httpClient.execute(...)`.

More implementation details from this [good `ExecutorService` tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Lastly, how about putting all of your messages into one entity and divide the messages on the server.  That would be the most efficient although you might not control the server handler code.

Comment: Thankyou so much. I have got log files and receivers at different machines so in this scenario am I gonna achieve the performance you mentioned for the other case?

Comment: If you have multiple different machines then firing the log files to different machines may indeed result in some performance improvements.  Hard to really know without more details @aneela.

Answer (score 2):

Hello ExecutorService is certainly an option.  You have 4 ways to do it in Java.

1. Using Threads (exposes to many details easy to make mistake)
2. Executor service as you have already mentioned. It comes from Java 6
   Here is a tutorial demonstrating ExecutorService http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html
3. ForkJoin framework comes from Java 7
4. ParallelStreams comes from Java 8 bellow is a solution using ParallelStreams

Going for higher level api will spare you some errors you might otherwise do.

```
receiversList.paralelstream().map(t->{
                                      String receiverURL = serverURL + receiversList.get(i);
                                      HttpPost method = new HttpPost(receiverURL);

                                             String logPath = logFilesPath + logFilesList.get(i);
                                             return readMsg(logPath);
                                             })
                                     .flatMap(t->t.stream)
                                     .forEach(t->{
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(message);
                        log.info("Sending message:");
                        log.info(message + "\n");
                        method.setEntity(entity);
                        if (receiverURL.startsWith("https")) {
                            processAuthentication(method, username, password);
                        }
                        httpClient.execute(method).getEntity().getContent().close();})
```

Comment: Thankyou so much but unfortunately I dont have java 8. If it isn't a burden can you give me a solution in 6 or 7 which I could understand better?